# Minimal popup in Javascript without any controls except X to close and _ to minimize

Tags: javascript, popup

I used the following to create a popup in Javascript:

```
var parms   = 'status=no,location=0,toolbar=0,menubar=no,dependent=yes,left=1000,top=100,';

var wh      = 'width=700,height=600';
popUpWin    = window.open("PopUpForImage.html", "imageWindow", parms + wh);
popUpWin.focus();
```

It creates a black (pop title) and a gray (webpage addres) area on top using Opera and Chrome

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Have you ever seen a popup like that on a webpage?

Comment: You mean without thoe top 2 lines? The answer is YES

Comment: I often see such popups as advertisements with an X to the right over the poopup.

Comment: But they are a part of the same website and not a new window

Comment: Possibly you are right and the ones I saw are part of a  ebpage. I will keep looking for examples.

Comment: Regardless, I am sure that  many would like to be able to launch and manage a very simple popup without any unneceasry information on top.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Comment: Thankj you for the inforation. I was not awar of the <dialog> option.

Ufortunately that is probably not what is neede in this case, but I will test to make sure. I ned a mnimal accessory popup which can show an image, its caption and resize automatically to adapt to picture size.

Comment: Per earlier comment I need a popup which displays images, their title and resized to adapt to omage size. Do you know how the image and a title can be changed each time the popup is needed? The titke oight to be a <p>.... </p> structure